# Add Flutter command-line arguments to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle

I've enabled null safety for my flutter project, but most of the libraries I need doesn't support it yet.

So I edited configuration in IntelliJ like this:
[image]

It works, but now I want to do the same in Android Studio to debug some java code and can't find place where to put it.

Would be even better, if someone points me to place in `build.gradle` for that.